# Scala : Need to create a newInstance of a class using Reflection that takes paramaters

Tags: scala, reflection, constructor

```
class Config(sourceName :String, storeClass :Class[_]) {

  def store = storeClass.getConstructor(classOf[Configuration]).newInstance(sourceName)

  def write(k :String, v :String) {
   store.writeTo(k,v)
  }

  def read(k :String): Unit ={
   store.readFrom(k)
  }

  def contains(k :String) :Boolean ={
   store.isContains(k)
  }
}
```

Here `Configuration` is a parent-abstract class whom are having some child classes.

So the 2nd parameter in `class config`, can be any child `class Configuration`.

And each child class takes a parameter while Initiating ie; `sourceName`.

```
storeClass.getConstructor(classOf[Configuration]).newInstance(sourceName)
```

This code above Return Type : `Any` , which create issue, since i need it to be of Type `Configuration`

```
def store :Configuration
```

to be of the Type `Configuration`, otherwise the `read`,`write` and `contains` won't work !

Comment: it was a basic mistake it should be .getConstructor(classOf[String]).newInstance(sourceName).asInstanceOf[configuration]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getConstructor` method selects a constructor that accepts parameters of the classes that you provide it. From your code it would appear that you want a constructor that accepts a `String`, so you probably want to do the following:

```
storeClass.getConstructor(classOf[String])
  .newInstance(sourceName)
  .asInstanceOf[Configuration]
```

But I'm not sure if that is the ideal solution to the problem you're trying to solve. Runtime reflection and `Class[_]` objects are not very Scala-esque...

Answer (score 2):

Cast it with `.asInstanceOf[Configuration]`. When using reflection, you have to expect to break type safety.

Comment: So what about the parameter sourceName ?

Comment: What about it? Just cast the result of `.newInstance(sourceName)`, so the line ends in `.newInstance(sourceName).asInstanceOf[Configuration]`.